# Object has no method replace in node-validator module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the following node module because I would like to prevent XSS:
https://github.com/chriso/node-validator

```
        str = str.replace(non_displayables[i], '');
                  ^
TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'replace'
    at remove_invisible_characters (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Dropbox\Nimble\node_mo
dules\validator\lib\xss.js:180:19)
```

I'm trying to sanitize the following information and create a JSON object:

```
var story = {
  _id:          sanitize(data._id).xss(),         //string
  title:        sanitize(data.title).xss(),       //string
  deadline:     sanitize(data.deadline).xss(),    //date string
  description:  sanitize(data.description).xss(), //string
  sp:           sanitize(data.sp).xss(),          //number
  value:        sanitize(data.value).xss(),       //number
  roi:          sanitize(data.roi).xss(),         //decimal number
  type:         sanitize(data.type).xss(),        //string
  lane:         sanitize(data.lane).xss()         //Typically 0
}
```

I'm including the module at the top of my code:     `sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;`

Lines 178 - 183 of xss.js from the module:

```
function remove_invisible_characters(str) {
    for (var i in non_displayables) {
        str = str.replace(non_displayables[i], '');
    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you're passing `0` (a number) into whatever function it is that's doing the `str = str.replace(...);` line. Numbers don't have the `replace` function. If that function expects and requires that its input be a string, you can ensure that by using `str = String(str).replace(...);` The `String` constructor, when called without `new`, does a type conversion; [details](http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.1).